# Android Studio 3.0 Beta5 Compiles Error

Tags: android, compiler-errors, sdk

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
/Users/nomankhan/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.0.2.aar/e49d52b74823e3f0f5498aa69c33e733/res/values/values.xml
Error:(1419, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
Error:(1419, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found
Error:/Clients/Shailesh/Evita/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1935 style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
Error:failed linking references
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 5s
>   Information:7 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

**style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<attr name="sc_corner_radius" format="dimension" />
<attr name="sc_border_width" format="dimension" />
<attr name="sc_tint_color" format="color" />
<attr name="sc_checked_text_color" format="color" />
```

Comment: please edit the question and share `values.xml`

Comment: @PeterHaddad i edited question, please have a look

Comment: Where are you using `windowsExitanimation`?

Comment: i m not using  windowsExitanimation, its throughing from appcompat-v7-26.0.2.aar/e49d52b74823e3f0f5498aa69c33e733/res/values/values.xml

Answer (score -2):

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

you should this line of code to gradle.properties